# Email body is blank when receiving it in GMAIL - Swiftmailer

Tags: php, email, gmail, swiftmailer

I have been having this issue, since I started using Swiftmailer. I know I am new at this so might be doing something wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

**Issue is:**
I receive blank body just in GMAIL but receive everything as expected in OUTLOOK/YAHOO.

I am not sure what the issue is. Thanks in advance for answering.

Here I call the function to send an email with all attributes

```
    $subject = "CROCT Admin - Evaluate performance of participant for project  - '".$result2['project_name']."'";
    $from = array('test@test.com' => 'Tasty');
    $to = $result4[$i]['email'];
    $body = 'Hello, You have got an invitiation to participate your work in project '.$result2['project_name'].' Accept the invitation and start participating in it.' .anchor('https://example.org/'.$project_id_url.'/'.$result4[$i]['user_id'], 'Accept Invitation');
    $addpart = 'Best,Team CROCT';
    $this->**send_email($subject, $from, $to, $body, $addpart)**;
```

Here is the function to send_mail

```
    function send_email($subject, $from, $to, $body, $addpart)
        {
            require_once APPPATH.'libraries/swift_mailer/swift_required.php';
            //Create the Transport
            $transport = Swift_MailTransport::newInstance();
            /*
            You could alternatively use a different transport such as Sendmail or Mail:
            //Sendmail
            $transport = Swift_SendmailTransport::newInstance('/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs');
            //Mail
            $transport = Swift_MailTransport::newInstance();
            */
            //Create the message
            $message = Swift_Message::newInstance();
            //Give the message a subject
            $message->setSubject($subject)
                    ->setFrom($from)
                    ->setTo($to)
                    ->setBody($body, 'text/plain')
                    ->addPart($addpart, 'text/html')
            ;
            //Create the Mailer using your created Transport
            $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
            //Send the message
            $result = $mailer->send($message);
            if ($result) {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Invitation sent.');
            } else {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Error occured.');
            }
        }
```

That's how I receive in Gmail
[image: Result I am getting in email - Just for GMAIL]

That's how I receive in Outlook
[image: This is what I receive in OUTLOOK]

[This is I received after change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTwKt.jpg)
[image]

Comment: Could you try removing the `->addPart($addpart, 'text/html')` and send it to gmail. What is your outcome?

Comment: Ahhhaaa... That worked. but gave me this as a result. **Hello, You have got an invitiation to participate your work in project Testing with criticallity<br/>Accept the invitation and start participating in it. <br/><a href="http://Example.com">Accept Invitation</a>** @JamieSterling

Comment: Try changing `->setBody($body, 'text/html')` and in your `$body` put the `$addpart` content into it,  don't use the `->addpart` section. Il put it inot an answer for you.

Comment: That's been resolved by changing **$body** to **text/html**. But now I receive an email as forwarded one. All the text I receive are coming as quoted text. @JamieSterling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As to the comments, this should be accepted by all major email providers.

Tested:

- gmail
- outlook
- yahoo
- kerio

MailFunction:

```
function send_email($subject, $from, $to, $body, $addpart)
        {
            require_once APPPATH.'libraries/swift_mailer/swift_required.php';
            //Create the Transport
            $transport = Swift_MailTransport::newInstance();
            /*
            You could alternatively use a different transport such as Sendmail or Mail:
            //Sendmail
            $transport = Swift_SendmailTransport::newInstance('/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs');
            //Mail
            $transport = Swift_MailTransport::newInstance();
            */
            //Create the message
            $message = Swift_Message::newInstance();
            //Give the message a subject
            $message->setSubject($subject)
                    ->setFrom($from)
                    ->setTo($to)
                    ->setBody($body, 'text/html')
            ;
            //Create the Mailer using your created Transport
            $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
            //Send the message
            $result = $mailer->send($message);
            if ($result) {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Invitation sent.');
            } else {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Error occured.');
            }
        }
```

Attributes:

```
$subject = "CROCT Admin - Evaluate performance of participant for project  - '".$result2['project_name']."'";
$from = array('test@test.com' => 'Tasty');
$to = $result4[$i]['email'];
$body = 'Hello, You have got an invitiation to participate your work in project '.$result2['project_name'].' Accept the invitation and start participating in it.' .anchor('https://example.org/'.$project_id_url.'/'.$result4[$i]['user_id'], 'Accept Invitation').'<br>Best,Team CROCT';
$this->**send_email($subject, $from, $to, $body)**;
```

Comment: That worked. But not sure what to do with text coming as quoted in email. It looks like forwarded email. I added image in question. @JamieSterling

Comment: Are these, single or double quotes? could add a link to a screen shot

Comment: I didnt get you. Link to where? I added screenshot to question. @jamiesterling

Comment: of the quoted email, upload the screenshot of the new email with the quotes to here http://imgur.com/ the comment the link

Comment: Added in question. also adding here [link]http://i.stack.imgur.com/kTwKt.jpg @jamiesterling

Comment: I don't know how but it solved itself. Your answer worked like charm. Thanks mate for helping out. Much appreciated. @jamiesterling

Comment: email to here for me, i'm thinking gmail is thinking its a reply. jamiestackoverflow@armyspy.com

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80184/discussion-between-dhavs-and-jamie-sterling).